# How to access complex R data structure fields from rpy2

Tags: rpy2, bioconductor

I am doing rna-seq expression analysis I am using the R packages bioconductor, limma edgeR. I have an DGElist returned by the featureCounts function. How can I access to the fields of this DGElist in python with rpy2?

I did `A=r("X<-featureCounts(...)")` but when I do `A["X"]` I can't see the fields as it appears in R. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most Bioconductor objects are using R's S4 system.

You can either rely on the accessor functions defined in the relevant R package or access the slots directly.

There is documentation about S4 with rpy2: http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/generated_rst/s4class.html

Otherwise, here the specific issue is that you are defining `X` in the R global environment. You will want to check an introduction to rpy2.